# determine context switch and copys within a range in my programm (C++) - debian

Tags: c++, copy, kernel, trace, context-switch

i want to determine the count of context switches and the copys that are needed for context switches within a range in my programm for e.g. (code line 100 - 300).

how can i do this?

i tried setting up lttng but i dont know how to read traces. The UST traces doesnt give me enought information, and the kernel traces are to complicated, or i just dont know how to interpret them.

is there other ways to count/determine it?

i am using debian.

thank you very much

Comment: Can you not just count them yourself?  If you make a system call in that range of lines, inc some 'contextChange' var, if the call asks for copying, eg read() or send(), inc some 'contextChangeAndCopy' var.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer. but i didnt get the idea with the system call, and how to do it. what do you mean exactly?